# trouble with adding a legend to a plot

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, legending

I am having trouble with adding a legend to a plot. 
this is my code,I tryed to use serval things,like

```
PlotLegends -> Automatic
PlotLegends -> {cVals[i]}
PlotLegends -> {i}
PlotLegends -> {cVals}
```

but they didn't give me what I hope!

what I want is writing the values of c in the plot,for example the red curve c=2.4
and the yellow curve c=2.2 ...etc

```
 Clear[t]
\[Tau] = 13.8;
\[Omega]0 = 1;
r = 0.7071;
n = 1.7758;
\[HBar] = 1.05457173*10^-34;
\[Omega] = 0.5;
k = 1666666.667;
s = 2.2758;
cVals = {2.4, 2.2, 2, 1.8, 1.5, 1.3};
color = {Red, Yellow, Green, Cyan, Blue, Orange};

Do[c = cVals[[i]];
 system1 = {x'[t] == n*y[t], y'[t] == -n*x[t] - c*z[t], 
   z'[t] == c*y[t]};
 initialvalues1 = {x[-20] == 0, y[-20] == 0, z[-20] == -1};
 sol1 = NDSolve[
   Join[system1, initialvalues1], {x[t], y[t], z[t]}, {t, -20, 20}];

 R = (-c*r*y[t]);

 Subscript[plotR, i] = 
  Plot[Evaluate[R /. sol1], {t, -20, 20}, FrameLabel -> {"t", "R"}, 
   Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> All, PlotStyle -> color[[i]], 
   PlotLegends -> {cVals[i]}];
 , {i, Length[cVals]}] 


Show[{Subscript[plotR, 1], Subscript[plotR, 2], Subscript[plotR, 3], 
  Subscript[plotR, 4], Subscript[plotR, 5]}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Clear[t]
\[Tau] = 13.8;
\[Omega]0 = 1;
r = 0.7071;
n = 1.7758;
\[HBar] = 1.05457173*10^-34;
\[Omega] = 0.5;
k = 1666666.667;
s = 2.2758;
cVals = {2.4, 2.2, 2, 1.8, 1.5, 1.3};
color = {Red, Yellow, Green, Cyan, Blue, Orange};

Do[c = cVals[[i]];
 system1 = {x'[t] == n*y[t], 
            y'[t] == -n*x[t] - c*z[t], 
            z'[t] == c*y[t]};
 initialvalues1 = {x[-20] == 0, y[-20] == 0, z[-20] == -1};
 sol1 = NDSolve[
   Join[system1, initialvalues1], {x[t], y[t], z[t]}, {t, -20, 20}];
 R = (-c*r*y[t]);
 Subscript[plotR, i] =
  Plot[Evaluate[R /. sol1], {t, -20, 20},
   FrameLabel -> {"t", "R"},
   Frame -> True,
   FrameTicks -> All,
   PlotStyle -> color[[i]],
   PlotLegends -> {Placed[
      Text[Style[" " <> ToString[cVals[[i]]] <> " ", Bold, 
        color[[i]], Background -> White]], {Center, Bottom}]}];, 
   {i, Length[cVals]}
 ]


Show[{Subscript[plotR, 1], Subscript[plotR, 2], Subscript[plotR, 3], Subscript[plotR, 4], Subscript[plotR, 5]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There might be a missing double square bracket (you want the $i$th part of the list `cVals` instead of calling a function with argument $i$), i.e. instead of

```
cVals[i]
```

use

```
cVals[[i]]
```

Replacing the following in the definition of Subscript in your code gives a rudimentary legend:

```
PlotLegends -> {"c=" <> ToString[cVals[[i]]]}
```

Comment: Work great! Thanks.